# Android - Puzzles about conversion between dp and pixel

Tags: android, screen, pixel, density-independent-pixel, screen-density

I know this might be a silly question but I have really gone through so many materiel and links but still not quite understand it. In the "Supporting Multiple Screens" section of Android Develop Doc, it introduces dp like this:

> ### Density-independent pixel (dp)
>
> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way. The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. **The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels.** You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

Basically I understand the fact that screen with higher dpi would have more pixels in a single physical inch, which means **a dp in such a screen would equal more physical pixels(px)**.

But according to the above conversion equation (in bold font), in a screen with higher dpi (e.g. 240 dpi screen) , a **px = (240 / 160) * dp = 1.5dp**. This seems to mean that in higher dpi screen **a px would equal more dp**. This looks in conflict with my previous understanding.

So, please, could anyone help me to figure this tricky issue out. Thank you a lot, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place in the formula. To see how many `dp` equals one `px` in different density, lets rearrange the formula:

```
px = dp * (dpi/160)
dp = px / (dpi/160)
```

Now for `1px`, in mdpi devices:

```
dp = 1 / (160/160) = 1dp
```

In hdpi devices:

```
dp = 1 / (240/160) = 0.666666667dp
```

You can see that 1px equals `less` dp in higher density devices

Comment: Hi Lawrence, thank you for your explanation and it is really strange about the way the conversion works, I would try to understand it. Thx.